# How to use ionic 4 search bar with *ngFor

Tags: ionic4

I have build a page that use a search bar to filter through an *ngFor array.  When I type in the search bar it behaves normally, but when I delete or back space text it does not update.  It works normally if I pull an array from a static list from a data service but not with the data I am pulling from an ApolloQueryResult.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div *ngIf="loading">Loading...</div>
  <div *ngIf="error">Error loading data</div>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionChange)="setFilteredItems()" showCancelButton="focus"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-card *ngFor="let data of info">
    <ion-card-content>
      {{data.TypeOfNotification}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { ApolloQueryResult } from 'apollo-client';
import { QueryTodoService } from '../../services/query-todo.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab-to-do',
  templateUrl: './tab-to-do.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab-to-do.page.scss'],
})

export class TabToDoPage implements OnInit {
  info: any;
  error: any;
  loading: boolean;
  searchTerm: string;

  constructor( 
    private apollo: Apollo,
    private queryTodoService: QueryTodoService,
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }

  setFilteredItems() {
    this.info = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
  }

  filterItems(searchTerm){
    return this.info.filter((item) => {
      return item.TypeOfNotification.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }

  // or

  setFilteredItemsAlt(event) {
    const searchTerm = event.srcElement.value;

    if (!searchTerm) {
      return;
    }

    this.info = this.info.filter(item => {
      if (item.TypeOfNotification && searchTerm) {
        if (item.TypeOfNotification.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('AccessToken').then((_token) => {
      this.apollo.watchQuery({
        query:this.queryTodoService.ToDoQuery,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
      })
      .valueChanges.subscribe((result: ApolloQueryResult<any> ) => {
        this.loading = result.loading;
        this.info = result.data.notifications.Notifications;
        console.log('first info', this.info );
        this.error = result.errors;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are overwriting `this.info` every time you fire `setFilteredItems()`:

```
setFilteredItems() {
    //Overwrite this.info with new filtered data set.
    this.info = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
}
```

The old values were filtered out and no longer exist - which is why `*ngFor="let data of info"` is not displaying them.

What you can do is set a new variable equal to `this.info` in your ts file - e.g. "dataDisplay":

```
dataDisplay: Array<object> = this.info;
```

Set this variable during an Ionic lifecycle change like `ionViewWillEnter` or whenever `this.info` gets set.

Then swap out the variable in `setFilteredItems()`:

```
setFilteredItems() {
    this.dataDisplay = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
}
```

Now change your `*ngFor` to the new variable:

```
*ngFor="let data of dataDisplay"
```

This should do the trick for you, because now `filterItems(searchTerm)` is always filtering the full, original `this.info` data set.